# visual studio performance, exit from debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance

I have win7, Intel i7, 64 with 64G Ram (8G page file on C Drive), C drive (system) on ssd, the solution on healthy HD. Why take 20 sec to exit debugging state? I see some Disk activity. how avoid this problem? it's not seem that performance on VS get better from my old pc.

Comment: Do u have debuggers in your app? I faced the same issue while starting/ending debug. This got fixed after removing the debug.

Comment: This is not normal.  You gave no hints whatsoever about what's special on your machine.  This just can't be guessed at.  Disable add-ins, look at network traffic, check if it repeats for small projects, etcetera.

Comment: PKKG: what mean remove debug?

Comment: Hans Passant: "this is not normal". how many sec on your system to exit from VB debugging mode? Also I clear, that I not have any Addins, and it is Winform solution with two project with some 2000 of line of code. I try again now. it's take 8 sec. for me it is long time, after I spend lot of many to buy high speed machine with SSD. I not see any Activities only on the disk. it's seem like Microsoft force unnecessary read and write of Gig from/to disk, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after I restart my PC it's down to about 2 sec. Still I see significant activity on disk, why?.